# How Many Queens to Threaten Themselves?

Tags: logical-deduction, optimization, chess

How many queens can be placed in a standard $8*8$ chessboard to threaten each of them exactly once by other queens?

Comment: Are other pieces allow on the board?

Comment: I might come up with a proper proof about those limits btw

Comment: that would be nice :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a 10 queen answer. I realized that d'alar'cop's reasoning was slightly off, because threatening is part of the puzzle, so 8 wasn't necessarily a limit. With the 8 inner queens in this position, you can put the final 2 queens in any 2 corners.

[image: 10 Queens]

Update: I have a proof for a maximum of 10 queens.

Given that 2 queens in a row or a column use 1x2 and 2 queens diagonally use 2x2, it is advantageous to avoid the diagonals.

Put 2 queens in a row. You have now used up 1 row and 2 columns.
Do this again. 2 rows, 4 columns.
Again. 3 rows, 6 columns.
If you do it a 4th time, you will have used all 8 columns, so don't.
Put 2 queens in a column. 5 rows, 7 columns.
Do this again. 7 rows, 8 columns.

You can no longer add any queens, as your columns are used up.
Repeat swapping columns and rows and you end up with 8 rows and 7 columns, so you still cannot add any queens.

Any attempts at using diagonals simply make the problem end faster (exception: a single diagonal, like my displayed answer, gets you to 8 rows, 8 columns).

Therefore, 10 queens is the maximum.

Now as for allowing other pieces, I noticed that there might be extra space from d'alar'cop's 24 queens answer, and I was able to get 2 more queens in.

[image: 26 Queens]

Comment: Nicely done. As expected all the columns and rows are occupied

Comment: awesome! I have been convinced that 8 is a limit :D thanks

Comment: I confirmed via integer linear programming that $10$ and $26$ are the optimal values for the two variants.

Answer (score 7):

A queen cannot have a paired queen on the same column if it also has one on the same row. So, queens will pair up every other row and every other column. This will yield 8 queens. There are many configurations (100s probably). Here is one example:

[image]

The question didn't strictly state if this matters, but I believe this is a maximum.

If other pieces are allowed, then other pawns can be used to block queens from each other. 24 queens can be placed on the board in this case.

[image]

Comment: Note that the original where this question comes from (how many queens can you place on a n*n board without any threatening another, without other pieces) also has n as solution. There's probably a paper worth of logic behind it, but it makes sense.

Comment: @Mast I thought that would be easier to prove. Because you can use the pigeon-hole-pricinple. With more than 8 queens, you'd have one row or column with 2 or more queens - i.e. threatening.