# How many Queens on a board

Tags: optimization, chess

Similarly to this question: [How many Queens to threaten themselves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/how-many-queens-to-threat-themselves).

What it the maximum number of queens you can place on an 8*8 board such that each queen is attacked precisely twice:

1. with no other pieces on the board?
2. other pieces are allowed?

I thought this was a legitimately interesting variation and it seems to be a more or less undocumented result as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update:
I was looking through old puzzles and saw this one and was always annoyed I couldn't get a 14th queen. So I found a way.
14 queens:
[image]

Original Answer:
I've managed 13 queens. I started in one corner and then put them on opposite diagonals. I then tweaked it so that all the queens were threatened twice. I was hoping for 14, but I'm starting to think 13 is the maximum.

[image: 13 Queens]

I've tried a few different ways with other pieces. The most I've managed is 32. Here's an alternative example:

[image: 32 Queens]

Comment: I'd move the corner queens one square just to provide more symmetry to the second solution. Also, there's no penalty to introducing more black pawns.

Comment: Only one more black pawn would be ok without ruining it. I'm a bit surprised about the lack of symmetry in the main solution. Also, what do you reckon about casting the problem as a graph problem to prove that 13 is the max?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to brute force it, as I'd have to read up on casting as a graph problem. Just been too long since I've done that.

Comment: I'm curious. Has anyone made progress towards brute forcing this?  It is not an easy problem to do that with as there are 47 trillion arrangments and no extremely easy was to shorten it.

Comment: I confirmed via integer linear programming that $14$ is optimal.

Comment: OK good. I was thinking 15 could happen but 16 was definitely out. I won't look for 15.

Comment: I also confirmed via integer linear programming that $32$ is optimal for the second variant with other pieces allowed.

Comment: There is essentially only one other $14$-queen solution:
\begin{matrix}
Q &. &Q &. &Q &. &Q &. &\\
Q &. &. &. &. &. &. &. &\\
. &. &. &. &. &Q &. &Q &\\
Q &. &. &. &. &. &. &. &\\
. &Q &. &. &. &. &. &. &\\
. &. &. &. &. &. &Q &. &\\
. &. &. &. &. &. &. &Q &\\
. &Q &. &Q &. &Q &. &. &\\
\end{matrix}

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution based on the other version of this problem: 12 queens.

[image]

I also found a solution where other pieces are permitted: 32 queens:

[image]

Comment: Can you get more than 32 if you try it on a diagonal, instead of horizontal?

Comment: @warspyking Try it. But I don't think so

Comment: I don't have a program to try it with.

Comment: @warspyking WinBoard for windows, xBoard for linux

Comment: I don't really like downloading things, have any online-mobile friendly sites?

Comment: I just imagined the board, it still only achieves 32 (snap)