# 3 Colors of Chess Pieces Attacking Each Other Once Each

Tags: combinatorics, chess, optimization

Yes, it's another "Chess Pieces Attacking Each Other" puzzle.  This time we have 3 colors.  Your goal is to place as many of the same type of chess piece (excluding pawns since you can't define the "forward" direction for 3 players) as possible onto an 8x8 board in 3 colors such that each piece attacks exactly 1 piece from each of the other colors.  Pieces may attack any number of their own color, these are ignored.  Note that there will necessarily be the same number of each color in every solution.

I have come up with a number of potentially optimal solutions (by hand, not verified by computer).  The number of pieces for each is hidden in the following hint.  Don't look if you'd rather see how many you can get on your own without knowing where the lower bar is, though I suspect that there is room for improvement on some of these.

> Bishops: 14 each
>  Knights: 10 each
>  Rooks: 20 each (fairly certain this is optimal)
>  Queens: 6 each
>  Kings: 12 each

Comment: By the way we can also ask for 4 colors (I have some solutions already). Also we can ask about attacking 2 opponent pieces and so on.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I have (I believe) optimal solutions for Knights and Kings in 4 colors, but they're pretty much identical to some of the 1- or 2- color solutions, so not very interesting.  4-color Queens might be worth a look.  Attacking 2 of each other color may be possible for Knights/Queens/Kings, but 3+ would definitely not be (unless there's only 2 colors, which we already did).  Another variation of this would be if you either forbid or require pieces attacking 1 of their own color.

Comment: I've posted the 4-color queens question here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95374/4-coloured-queens-attacking-every-opponent-queen-once

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Bishops](https://lichess.org/editor/1B1BB1B1/bB1PP1Bb/P1bPPb1P/bbPbbPbb/BPbBBbPB/1PBBBBP1/1bPBBPb1/2PbbP2_w_-_-_0_1)

> 16 each
>
> ```
>  . A . A A . A .
>  B A . C C . A B
>  C . B C C B . C
>  B B C B B C B B
>  A C B A A B C A
>  . C A A A A C .
>  . B C A A C B .
>  . . C B B C . .
> ```

[Knights](https://lichess.org/editor/Nnb2bnN/Nnb2bnN/bnN2Nnb/bnN2Nnb/8/n2NN2n/2bbbb2/1Nn2nN1_w_-_-_0_1)

> 12 each
>
> ```
>  A B C . . C B A
>  A B C . . C B A
>  C B A . . A B C
>  C B A . . A B C
>  . . . . . . . .
>  B . . A A . . B
>  . . C C C C . .
>  . A B . . B A .
> ```

[Rooks](https://lichess.org/editor/RbbRrrRb/rrrRbbRr/bR1RbbRr/bRrrrrRb/rRbbR1Rb/rRbbRrrr/bRrrRbbR/8_w_-_-_0_1)

> 18 each
>
> ```
>  A B B A C C A B
>  C C C A B B A C
>  B A . A B B A C
>  B A C C C C A B
>  C A B B A . A B
>  C A B B A C C C
>  B A C C A B B A
>  . . . . . . . .
> ```

[Queens](https://lichess.org/editor/Q1k2k1Q/q1q2q1q/k1Q2Q1k/8/8/k1Q2Q1k/q1q2q1q/Q1k2k1Q_w_-_-_0_1)

> 8 each
>
> ```
>  A . B . . B . A
>  C . C . . C . C
>  B . A . . A . B
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  B . A . . A . B
>  C . C . . C . C
>  A . B . . B . A
> ```

[Kings](https://lichess.org/editor/1KkpKkp1/p6K/k1KkkK1k/K1p2p1p/p1p2p1K/k1KkkK1k/K6p/1pkKpkK1_w_-_-_0_1)

> 12 each
>
> ```
>  . A B C A B C .
>  C . . . . . . A
>  B . A B B A . B
>  A . C . . C . C
>  C . C . . C . A
>  B . A B B A . B
>  A . . . . . . C
>  . C B A C B A .
> ```

Comment: Nice, you squeezed a few more bishops and queens than I was able to.  My kings solution is a completely different arrangement, but same number so this is valid.

Comment: @Darrel Those knights were challenging. Solutions with 8 each were easy, but I was not able to get 10. Then suddenly...

Comment: Your knights solution is almost the same as mine, actually, at least the top half is.  But you managed to squeeze in two more on the bottom, so congrats again.  If you can beat my 20 rook solution I'll be really impressed.  (21 is the theoretical maximum, but I'm *pretty* sure that's impossible?  Might be proven wrong again though...)

Comment: @Darrel I've added a solution for rooks. Only 18 each, buy I probably won't spend much more time on it.

Comment: Hmm, so should I wait a bit before posting my rook solution?  You'll probably get the checkmark of course, since you solved 4/5 of them, in 3 cases better than mine, so unless someone finds even better solutions, it's yours, but if I close it now it might discourage others from trying.  Maybe I'll give it another day or so.

Comment: Since nobody else seems to be trying anymore, I added my 20 rook solution below.  I was considering expanding this to 4 colors for completion (certainly can't do more with any piece), but the Knights and Kings solutions are pretty much identical to some of the 1- and 2- color solutions, which would just leave Queens since Bishops and Rooks definitely can't do 4.  Might just put as an addendum...

Answer (score 5):

Via integer linear programming, the maximum for knights is

> [image]

The maximum for queens is at least

> [image]

Other maxima are

> 20 rooks, 16 bishops, 12 kings

Comment: Ooh, that Queens solution is funky.  You expect to see some sort of symmetry on most of these and then boom, total random mess, but it works.  Not sure what to do with the checkmark at this point since the answers are pretty evenly split...

Answer (score 2):

Here are my own solutions I put together.  With the exception of the Rooks solution, they have already been equaled or surpassed by Daniel's answer, so I'm just posting them for comparison.

Bishops:

> 14 of each can fit:
>
> ```
>  . B . A . C . .      . B A A B C C .
>  A . C . B . A .     A B C C B A A B
>  . C . . . . . B     . C C . . . A B
>  . . B . . . . .     . . B A . C . .
>  . . . A . C . .     . . B A . C . .
>  . . C . . . A .     . C C . . . A B
>  . B . C . A . B     A B C C B A A B
>  . . A . B . C .     . B A A B C C .
>  Just one color       Both together
> ```

Rooks:

> 20 of each can fit:
>
> ```
>  C B B C C B B C
>  A A A A A A A A
>  B C C B B C C B
>  B C C B B C C B
>  A A A A A A A A
>  C . . C C . . C
>  B B B B B B B B
>  A C C A A C C A
> ```

Knights:

> 10 of each can fit:
>
> ```
>  A C B . . B C A
>  A C B . . B C A
>  B C A . . A C B
>  B C A . . A C B
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . A A . . .
>  . . C . . C . .
>  . . . B B . . .
> ```

Queens:

> 6 of each can fit:
>
> ```
>  A B . . B A . .
>  C . . . . C . .
>  C . . . . C . .
>  A B . . B A . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  A . . . . . . .
>  . . . . B . . .
>  B . C C A . . .
> ```

Kings:

> 12 of each can fit:
>
> ```
>  A B B A . A B . 
>  C . . C . C . B
>  C . . C . . C A
>  A B B A . . . .
>  . . . . A C C A
>  A B . . B . . B
>  C . B . B . . B
>  . C A . A C C A
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have improved the queens solution

> 9 Queens each!
>
> ```
>  3 . 2 . . 2 3 3
>
>  3 . . . . . . .
>
>  2 1 1 . . . . .
>
>  . . 1 1 1 2 . 2
>
>  . 1 . 1 . . . 1
>
>  2 . . . . 2 . .
>
>  . . 3 . . . . .
>
>  2 3 3 . 1 2 3 3
> ```

or

> ```
>  3 . . 1 . 1 . 3
>
>  2 . . 1 1 . . 2
>
>  2 2 . . . . 2 2
>
>  . . . . 3 . . 2
>
>  . . 3 3 3 . . .
>
>  1 . 3 3 3 . . 1
>
>  1 . . . . . 1 .
>
>  2 . . 2 . 1 . .
> ```

some more

> ```
>  1..2.2.1
>
>  3..22..3
>
>  33....33
>
>  ...11...
>
>  2..11.2.
>
>  2.111...
>
>  3......3
>
>  3..2..2.
>
>
>
>  ..1.33.2
>
>  3...33..
>
>  ..22..11
>
>  1222..1.
>
>  ..22....
>
>  1......1
>
>  ..113...
>
>  33...3.2
>
>
>
>  3..2...2
>
>  1..2....
>
>  .1....11
>
>  1..33..1
>
>  .13333..
>
>  ...33...
>
>  22....22
>
>  .2.11.2.
> ```

Comment: Oops looks like I was beaten to this.

Comment: It's alright, these are interesting too - strange that all of the 9-queen solutions are all just an asymmetrical mess.  I wonder if there's one with a nice pattern like the others?  (I know there's only 1 symmetrical solution to the old 8 colorless queens problem, excluding rotations/reflections.)

Comment: I don't yet know that 9 is optimal, so there might still be an opportunity to improve this.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, if you require 180-degree rotational symmetry in the occupancy pattern (ignoring colors), 8 is optimal.

Comment: @RobPratt No, it's not required, I was just curious as to why everything else can be managed with some symmetry except for the queens.  It's certainly mathematically interesting that a symmetrical solution does not appear to exist.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I just mean if you impose that additional constraint, it reduces the maximum to 8.  Same is true for both types of reflections.

Comment: I've added some more. I am guessing 3x9 is difficult to place in a symmetric fashion. If a solution with 10 exists then it could be symmetrical...