# 4-coloured queens attacking every opponent queen once

Tags: combinatorics, chess

Can you place 6 queens from four different colours (24 in total), such that each queen attacks exactly one queen of each colour? They may attack as many queens of their own colour as these are ignored.

Here is a similar question: [3 Colors of Chess Pieces Attacking Each Other Once Each](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95214/3-colors-of-chess-pieces-attacking-each-other-once-each/)

Comment: I had a solution for this a few days ago, but I'm having trouble now...? btw: [6×6 in 106](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/rotating-numbers-in-a-3x3-grid)

Comment: Oooh cool! I will try 6x6 Now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[lichess link](https://lichess.org/editor/kQ3Qq1/qK2K2q/4k2Q/5kK1/1Kk5/q2k4/Q2K2KQ/1Qq3qk_w_-_-_0_1)

> ```
>  A B . . . B C .
>  C D . . D . . C
>  . . . . A . . B
>  . . . . . A D .
>  . D A . . . . .
>  C . . A . . . .
>  B . . D . . D B
>  . B C . . . C A
> ```

Comment: Nice solution. I have a different one which I will post later.

Answer (score 5):

You asked for 6 queens, but the maximum is at least

> [image]

Comment: I even thought to suggest that you would find a better solution with your programming...

Comment: Wow! I could not find 7 queens with my program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I had in mind:

> ```
>  . . . . 3 1 . .
>
>  . . . . 4 2 . .
>
>  . 1 3 . . . . .
>
>  . 2 4 . . . 4 2
>
>  . . . . . . 3 1
>
>  4 2 . 2 4 . . .
>
>  3 1 . 1 3 . 3 1
>
>  . . . . . . 4 2
> ```