# Queens attacking exactly four queens

Tags: combinatorics, chess

Can you place 14 black and 14 white queens on a standard 8x8 chess board, such that each queen attacks exactly 4 opponent queens?

Good luck!

Here is a related question: [Queens attacking exactly one queen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94405/queens-attacking-exactly-one-queen)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I hope this is correct. First, I noticed that these 8 queens close to the corners fulfill the conditions.
>  Then I tried to add more queens while blocking already set queens to not increase their attacks.
>
>  [image]
>  [lichess](https://lichess.org/editor/1q1Qq1Q1/Q6q/3Qq3/q1qQqQ1Q/Q1QqQq1q/3qQ3/q6Q/1Q1qQ1q1_w_-_-_0_1)

Comment: Seems right to me, i'm impressed. Tried to solve it for like 30 min without being able to, assumed it would have a 90 degree rotation symmetry but seems like it only needs to be a 180 degree symmetry.

Comment: That is exactly the pretty solution I was looking for! Very well done. I wasn't sure that anyone would get it so quickly.

Comment: @Dmitry An [alternative solution](https://lichess.org/editor/2Q2q2/1q4Q1/Q1qQqQ1q/2QqQq2/2qQqQ2/q1QqQq1Q/1Q4q1/2q2Q2_w_-_-_0_1)

Comment: Very nice Daniel! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly there exist completely non-symmetric solutions:

> [image]

And this one

> [image]

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: I used a computer program based on hill climbing